# Solana airdrop tcp error in localhost network

Tags: solana

```
-> solana-keygen (BIP39 none)

-> config be url as localhost

-> Phantom localhost nwtwork

-> airdrop specifying the key, pubkey, and --url on localhost.
```

These steps, which seem to me to be correct, return the following error:

````
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://localhost/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente. (os error 10061)```
````

Answer (score 2):

When you run a local validator with `solana-test-validator`, the main RPC port will be 8899 by default, so you need to specify `http://localhost:8899` as your cluster URL.